# QML: Trigger functionality for all delegate instances

Tags: qt, qml, components

I searched alot on google/stackoverflow for this problem but didn't find a solution which worked for me. I already learned that accessing a childs id/properties is not doable without some tricks. 
I tried using multiple alias properties but I cannot make a alias chain because I cannot define properties in a Component.

My problem is that I got a MainGrid.qml (GridView) which displays all my videos and a Footer.qml in which I want to implement a playbar.

```
GridView {


x: videoWallWindow.x
y: videoWallWindow.y
width: videoWallWindow.width
height: videoWallWindow.height
cellWidth: 300
cellHeight: 300

property alias deleg : loader.item

Loader {
    id: loader
    sourceComponent: videoDelegate
    visible: false
}

Component {
    id: videoDelegate
    Rectangle {
        id: container
        property alias streamVid : stream
        width: 256
        height: 240
        color: "#4f4f4f"
        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 3
        Stream {
            id: stream
        }

        Playbar {
            x: 0
            y: container.height - 20
            width: container.width
            height: 20
        }

        Text {
            id: textId
            text: name //defined in a ListModel

        }
    }
}

model: StreamList {}
delegate: videoDelegate
focus: true
}
```

(MainGrid.qml)
(tired with alias properties and my last try was with a Loader)

```
ToolBar {

property MainGrid myGrid

id: footer
x: 0
y: window.height - footer.height
width: window.width
background: Rectangle {
    implicitHeight: 45
    color: "#212121"

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: 1
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "#212121"
    }
}

Row {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    PlaybarButton {
        id: pauseButton
        height: footer.height
        width: footer.height

        property bool currentState: true

        onClicked: {
            currentState ? myGrid.deleg.streamVid.pause() : myGrid.deleg.streamVid.play() //<----- here is the problem
            currentState = !currentState
        }
        Image {
            id: pauseImage
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: parent.currentState ? ("pics/pause.png") : ("pics/play.png")
        }
    }
}
}
```

(Footer.qml)

```
Video {
id: streamVideo
width: mainGrid.cellWidth
height: mainGrid.cellHeight
anchors.fill: parent

source: portrait //defined as the path in a ListModel

MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        video.playbackState == MediaPlayer.PlayingState ? video.pause() : video.play()
    }
}
autoPlay: true
loops: MediaPlayer.Infinite
focus: true

}
```

(Stream.qml)

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: window
visible: true

width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight

...
MainGrid {
    id: mainGrid
}

Footer {
    id: footer
    myGrid: mainGrid
}
}
```

(main.qml)

So I hope the code is readable enough. Can anybody help me figure out how to properly access the video/stream in my Footer.qml from my GridView (MainGrid.qml). Or do I have to completely reconstruct my current program?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Changed the title to reflect the actual problem you went the wrong way about fixing, so it is more useful for people who search for similar stuff in the future. Aliases should be used to introduce modularity, and are absolutely not the solution to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access anything inside a delegate from the outside, because a delegate is just a prototype for objects to be created. You can only access stuff that is in the delegate's actual instance objects.

However, delegates can still access stuff that's outside of them, because that's defined object structure.

Since what you want to do is play or pause all videos in every delegate, the easiest solution would be to bind to an external property or signal that is somewhere down the object tree. For example:

```
// in main.qml
signal togglePlayback

// in delegate
Connections {
  target: mainQMLFile
  onTogglePlayback: video.playbackState == MediaPlayer.PlayingState ? video.pause() : video.play()
}
```

You can also pass an actual value through the signal and check that to get consistent behavior across all delegates, on the odd chance you get status mismatches, in order to achieve consistent state rather than just flip between play and pause.

Comment: But I need to access the MainGrid in the Footer. I understand that it works the same way but for some reason if I try mainGrid.videoDelegate.container.video.play() in my Footer.qml it will not work. Even if they meet in the main.qml with MainGrid having the mainGrid as id.Or do you mean that I have to add the MainGrid in my Footer.qml so I can access and display it from there instad of displaying it in main.qml

Comment: @NhatNienne you have `GridView`'s `currentItem` property. Obviously if you want to access a particular delegate instance, you have to be able to specify which one. So you either use the current item or use some other method to specify an index or something. Your current design is pretty messy, you should clean it up and streamline it.

Comment: The thing is I do not try to pause/play one video but try to hit all Items in my delegate. Is  this possible?

Comment: Well yes, you can iterate in a loop all of the view items and hit them one by one manually. Or you could have a single bool property that's in `main.qml` and bind the delegate to it, and then only change the property and have bindings handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Then I am going to try to integrate this in my main.qml and test it out.

Comment: How do I actually input a value to the signal? I got your example implemented but fail to understand how I get the signal from main.qml linked to the Button in my Footer.qml so that when it is pressed the signal is triggered. Edit: Do I have to make a Connection in the Footer.qml same way I did with MainGrid.qml? And if so how can I link the Connection to my PlaybarButton

Comment: In the footer `onClicked: togglePlayback()` should be enough. Or you could define the signal as `signal togglePlayback(value)` and then `togglePlayback(true)` or false, and you will also have access to `value` in the handler so you can directly `if (value) pause() else play()`

Comment: Okay now I think I understand the usage and purpose of signals! Thanks for  explaining it to me. It works the exact same way I wanted it to

Comment: Signals are pretty handy. This stuff is its basic, intended usage, but you can also do some pretty crazy and powerful things with them. A `Connections` element is only needed if you make the connection from outside the element, in your case you make it from the button's handler hook and the signal itself can be resolved because of dynamic scoping. There is also the imperative syntax `someSignal.connect(someFoo)`.